# How can I transfer DotFolders from my Note 3 to my Windows computer?

Tags: windows, android, file-management, dotfiles

Okay so I made a hidden folder(Period before it) on my phone with very important photos/videos. Now my Note 3s screen cracked and so is it back light..
I have my phone hooked up (usb) to my computer(windows) and I cant find that folder.. I named it ".Private" on my phone and now I can't find it on my computer. Please help guys! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Organize (sic) menu, select Folder and Search Options, View, and then enable "Show hidden files, folders and drives". hope this is already dealt with.

Pretty much straight forward, i assume [Check this out](http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Android-System-Files) or this list of numerous [alternatives](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-access-sd-card-system-files-on-android-from-your-comuputer/)

Comment: I'm not able to access my Note 3. the screen is cracked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to show hidden files/folders on your computer?

If you are on Windows, you can enable it at this way:
Control Panel > Folder Options > View tab > check Show Hidden files folders and drives

Comment: This may be better as a comment